# Append several NodeLists in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodelist

I've been trying for hours to append three NodeLists and failing. Can you please help me?

I've made following code:

```
NodeList nList = root.getElementsByTagName("res");
NodeList nList2 = root.getElementsByTagName("agr");
NodeList nList3 = root.getElementsByTagName("rag");

NodeList allNodes = appendNodeLists(nList, nList2, nList3);
```

and the appendNodeLists method:

```
   public static NodeList appendNodeLists(NodeList a, NodeList b, NodeList c)
   {
     NodeList nList;
       int aSize = a.getLength();
       int bSize = b.getLength();
       int cSize = c.getLength();
       if(aSize>0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++) 
               nList.item(i) = a.item(i);  //Error in this line
       }
       if(bSize>0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < bSize; i++) 
               nList.item(aSize+1+i) = b.item(i); //Error in this line                    
       }
       if(cSize>0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < bSize; i++)
               nList.item(aSize+bSize+1+i) = c.item(i);  //Error in this line            
       }

       return nList;
   }
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't append the 3 NodeLists and I can't seem to figure out why.

Btw, I have the same error in 3 lines: "Unexpected type - required variable - found value".
Why is this happening?

Comment: I've seen it. I've managed to make it work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that:

```
nList.item(i)
```

gets a value where as it looks like you are trying to set a value to it.  You can not assign anything to `nList.item(i)`.  The `NodeList` interface itself does not have operations for appending new items into the list.  You might want to look at the underlying type of `NodeList` and see if you can add items to that.  Also, you are not constructing the `nList` variable.  `NodeList` is an interface.  What were you going to create that as?

If you don't want that as a `NodeList`, you could very easily do it as a regular `List<Node>` instead.  Something like this:

```
   List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
   int aSize = a.getLength();
   int bSize = b.getLength();
   int cSize = c.getLength();
   if(aSize>0)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++) 
           nodes.add(a.item(i));
   }
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can't get the sub-elements from a node if they're in a normal ArrayList. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sure you can.  A `Node` is still a `Node` regardless of what data structure its being stored in (`NodeList` vs regular `List`).  Give it a shot and post back if you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use NodeList, you can do this:

```
nList.item(i).setNodeValue(a.item(i).getNodeValue());
```

The better way to do it is just with a List as cmbaxter suggested, though.

```
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) doesn't expose any methods to mutate its state, you can implement your own version to concatenate the lists:

```
  public static NodeList join(final NodeList... lists) {
    class JoinedNodeList implements NodeList {
      @Override
      public int getLength() {
        int len = 0;
        for (NodeList list : lists) {
          len += list.getLength();
        }
        return len;
      }

      @Override
      public Node item(int index) {
        for (NodeList list : lists) {
          if (list.getLength() > index) {
            return list.item(index);
          } else {
            index -= list.getLength();
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }

    return new JoinedNodeList();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`NodeList` by itself is pretty basic and is used just to iterate over the `Node`s. To create a new `NodeList` use an `Element` after passing the root `Document` object to your method as follows.

```
public static NodeList appendNodeLists(Document root,
                                       NodeList a, NodeList b, NodeList c)
{
    Element allNodes = root.createElement("allNodes");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.getLength(); i++)
        allNodes.appendChild(a.item(i));

    for (int i = 0; i < b.getLength(); i++) 
        allNodes.appendChild(b.item(i));

    for (int i = 0; i < c.getLength(); i++)
        allNodes.appendChild(c.item(i));

    return allNodes.getChildNodes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this - note that as you append the child, you're actually moving it from one element to another, so the index number stays the same.

```
public void appendNodeList(Element TargetElement, NodeList nl) {

    int cnt = nl.getLength();

    for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
        TargetElement.appendChild(nl.item(0)); 
    }

}
```